# Micronaut with remote Swagger-UI / CORS error

Tags: cors, swagger-ui, micronaut

At the moment I'm struggling with Micronaut 1.2.5 and a remote Swagger-UI. My idea is to collect several APIs in one Swagger-UI instance.

In my Micronaut project I'm able to create a valid Swagger YAML file and with this solution [Swagger for Micronaut with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551178/swagger-for-micronaut-with-maven) (serve static Swagger-UI page in my project) everything works fine.

To let Micronaut work with a remote Swagger-UI which resides in another domain than my service I did the following settings in application.yml:

```
micronaut:
  server:
    cors:
      endabled: true
      configurations:
        web:
          exposedHeaders:
            - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
            - Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            - Access-Control-Allow-Methods
```

Unfortunately, this does not help, Swagger-UI fails with

```
Fetch error
NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. https://....yml

Fetch error
Possible cross-origin (CORS) issue? The URL origin (https://aa) does not match the page (https://bb). Check the server returns the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-*' headers.
```

In the Micronaut response, no Access-Control-Allow headers are contained. While debugging CorsFilter seems not to be called, the breakpoint in the doFilter method has no effect.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance,
Christoph

Comment: Typo? Does your config file literally have `endabled: true`? If so, that needs to instead be `enabled: true`, right?

Comment: You are right, fixing the type enabled cors. I also changed the exposedHeaders. But unfortunately this helps only sometimes and only in Firefox, Chrome and Edge have the same error message.

Answer (score 3):

After some investigation I was able to solve the problems.

My application.yaml looks now like this:

```
micronaut:
  server:
    cors:
      enabled: true
      configurations:
        web:
          exposedHeaders:
            - Content-Type
            - Authorization
            - '*'
```

The issues regarding Chrome and Edge were caused by self signed SSL certificates, which were not accepted.

To solve that it helps to open the swagger.yml file in your browser and add the self signed SSL certificate to your browser. After that you are able to use your Micronaut API in Swagger.

Comment: I have the same issue. I added your applicatoin.yaml and I see new headers with a POST or a PUT but not for a GET on an api nor on the GET for the swagger.yml file. I use http would that be a problem?