# Micronaut CORS setting not working as expected from hls.js XmlHttpRequest

Tags: angular, cors, micronaut, hls.js

Hi I have created an api interface which serves `master.m3u8` file which has internally link to other `playlist.m3u8` file in `http://path to resource pattern`

My API development framework is `micronaut`.

My `application.yml` setting is as below:

```
---
micronaut:
  application:
    name: kuchipuchipoo
  server:
    cors:
      enabled: true
      configurations:
        web:
          allowCredentials: true
          allowedMethods:
            - OPTIONS
            - POST
            - PUT
            - GET
          exposedHeaders:
            - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
            - Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            - Access-Control-Request-Method
            - Access-Control-Request-Headers
            - Origin
            - Cache-Control
            - Content-Type
            - Authorization
    port: 9093
    max-request-size: 256MB
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 256MB
---
```

When I try to hit this request from hls.js i.e play() command I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9093/path?params' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

AFAIR, I have added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in application config still that doesn't seem to have any effect.

My Client application is in angular 7+, both are separate apps running on different port just to be clear.

**EDITED**

Ugly work around is below server implementation:

```
@Get("/path/to/playlist.m3u8")
    @Produces("application/x-mpegURL")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    public HttpResponse<File> getResolutionFileNew(vars id) {
        MutableHttpResponse<File> ok = HttpResponse.ok(fileDeliveryManager.getResolutionsFile(id));
        return ok.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
    }

    @Get("/path/to/file{index}.ts")
    @Produces("video/MP2T")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    public HttpResponse<File> getFileChunk(vars id) {
        final File file = fileDeliveryManager.getChunkFile(file0.ts, id);
        log.debug("Transporting ts file {}", file);
        MutableHttpResponse<File> ok = HttpResponse.ok(file);
        return ok;
    }
```

If I don't add `ok.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");` it just doesn't work.

I am fully confused here, seem cors settings in application.yml are doing nothing.
Previous I have worked with spring boot api framework, and we don't have to dump header in such way, I am definitely doing something wrong here, but not able to figure out. Any help would help me.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: it is 200 response, infact the response also is valid but same request is showing cors error in console tab, and it is just a single api call i made sure its not triggering twice

Comment: Any update on this, facing same issue. CORS is not working in Micronaut

Comment: @KeshavAggarwal check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734101/micronaut-with-remote-swagger-ui-cors-error/58745563#comment107620211_58745563

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `micronaut.server.cors.single-header: true`. Some browsers don't follow the standard of having multiple headers.

Comment: I have same issue, cors.enable doesn't work in my project

Comment: Check edited section, i managed to make it work somehow because my server only serves index and chunk files no other apis are implemented in this, this is so trivial issues.

Comment: @Amateur Please upload an example application to github that reproduces the issue and include it in an issue report at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core. Without something to debug I'm afraid I can't be of much help

Comment: @JamesKleeh, if I enable only micronaut.server.cors, it doesn't work. But it works if I add more config like in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734101/micronaut-with-remote-swagger-ui-cors-error/58745563#comment107620211_58745563

Thanks for your consideration